# Site CSS Fails To Load (sometimes)

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, css, helix3

- Joomla 3.6.5
- Helix Framework Version: 1.8
- SEF & URL Rewriting enabled (No third party extensions installed)
- Helix3 Template [link](http://demo.joomshaper.com/?template=helix3)
- System & page cache off

I am facing a strange problem with my website in that sometimes the page will load with **no styling**.

This doesn't happen on every page refresh, It's very intermittent (I'd estimate about 1 in 20 page refreshes result in the page loading with no styling). I thought the issue was somehow related to my localhost (XAMPP) environment however I have since uploaded my site to a live hosting environment (JustHost) and the exact same thing is happening.

Is the issue likely to be template / framework related, or a conflict with another script? I've read that it could be related to `http / https` or `htaccess`? [Here's a link](http://pastebin.com/raw/xXmFcyUm) to my htaccess file.

Thanks to advice from @Lodder, I've inspected the css files in the `<head>` using devtools, and it seems that the issue is related to the following file;

```
<link href="/dod-localnew/cache/com_templates/templates/shaper_helix3/2fe4c35dd273afe1ee67195bbd402c15.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

If I delete this file in devtools this is how my page looks with no styling. SO it would appear this file isn't loading each time?

Note, I am testing in my local environment.

I can't get any official support for Helix3 from Joomshaper without a paid subscription.

Any tips on troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you made any changes to your `.htaccess` file? Do you have any form of caching enabled? If so, try disabling it.

Comment: When there's no styling on the page, open your browser dev tools, go to the inspector, and see if the CSS file (`<link href="path/to/file.css" />`) actually exists

Comment: In which case the caching is probably coming from the helix 3 template settings. Try disabling it as shown here: https://www.joomshaper.com/documentation/helix3/advanced-settings

Comment: That will be the expected result, cause when you have the setting enabled, it will most likely be merging the CSS files into 1 file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.htaccess` file is example the same as the one shipped with Joomla, so no changes have been made there.

If both the system and page cache are disabled, then it may be a caching related issue.

To check if a cached version of the CSS file is being called, open up your browser console, and inspect the `<head>` element. You should see `cache/` in the URL of the stylesheet.
If you do, check for a cache option in the template settings, as the main template providers tend to add their own....JoomShaper (Helix 3) being one of them.

---

In the following documentation, You'll see an option to disabled CSS Compression:

https://www.joomshaper.com/documentation/helix3/advanced-settings